# Multidimensional Monte Carlo Method

Tags: python, integration, montecarlo

I am trying to evaluate the following multidimensional integral:

[Integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dThZc.png)

[image]

with the answer being 155/6. However the Python code I've used:

[Attempted Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uogXr.png)

[image]

doesn't work. How do I correct or what code should I do instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please don't post code as an image.  Copy/paste the code into your question as text properly formatted.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! You're much more likely to get help if you format your code into your question. This gives potential answerers a place to start from, rather than transcribing a photo of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of bugs in your code.

Most important one is when you square point first and sum later, not as shown in formula. Then you divide by 'n' which is undefuned.

Here is correct code

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

D = 10
N = 1000000

I = 0.0

for k in range(0, N):
    pt = rng.random(D)
    I += np.sum(pt)**2

print(I/N*6.0/155.0)
```

On Python 3.8.5 x64, windows 10, it prints

```
0.9996726183447514
```